# Error with a bash loop for sqlite insert

Tags: bash, loops, sqlite, insert

I'm trying to insert stuff in db whith a while loop, but after 2 inserts my loop break ...
here the code:

```
x=0
while [[ "$x" < 10 ]];do
    ((x++))
    sqlite my_db.db "insert into (col) values ('$x...')
done
```

So I tried to do that  but unsuccess too.

```
y=0
x=0
while [[ "$y" < 5 ]];do
    while [[ "$x" < 10 ]];do
        ((x++))
        sqlite my_db.db "insert into (col) values ('$x...')"
    done
    ((y++))
done
```

But once again its only insert 2 times ...
So why did i have this error and how to fixe that ? thx.

Comment: Tip: [ShellCheck](http://shellcheck.net) detects common problems, including this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

< and > are string comparison operators.
For integers you must use -lt (less than) and -gt (greater than) respectively.
Also close the query string.

```
x=0
while [[ "$x" -lt 10 ]];do
    ((x++))
    sqlite my_db.db "insert into (col) values ('$x...')"
done
```

Comment: Thx you ... shame on me for don't trying this ..And the unclosed query is a typo (i'm on mobile).

Answer (score 1):

Because your code never resets x to 0 (or anything less than 10). Additionally, you're using the wrong operator (which is why the first snippet isn't working).

```
x=0
y=0
while [[ $y -lt 5 ]];do
   x=0
   while [[ $x -lt 10 ]];do
      ((x++))
      sqlite my_db.db "insert into (col) values ('$x...')
   done
   ((y++))
done
```